# Placing a div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I´m got a div (.work) as background, inside that I got another div (.subject, got 6 of these) and another div inside (.slider). I´m using the same styling to both the .subject and the .slider but the .slider isn´t beeing placed inside the .subject div. It is placed in the .work div

This is what I got:

```
<div class="work">
<div class="subject" id="1">  
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
<div class="subject" id="2">
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

<div class="subject" id="3">
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

<div class="subject" id="4">
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

<div class="subject" id="5">
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

<div class="subject" id="6">
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

css

```
.work {
left: 1%;
top: 11.5%;
height:85.5%;
width:30%;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
            0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
border: 1px soid F2F2F2(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
z-index:-1;
overflow: auto;
}
.subject {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:25%;
width:90%;
background-color:#0D7BFF;
border-radius:1px;
margin-top:5%;
}

.slider {
top:70%;
bottom:0%;
left:0%;
right:0%;
position:absolute;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
opacity:0.9;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I could get the .slider inside all of the .subject without having to make separate css for all of the .subjects

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `position:absolute;` on `.slider` style, which means it is out of flow of the page.

Try adding `position:relative;` into your `.subject` class.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the value of the `position` property to `relative` for the `.slider` element.

```
.slider {
    top:70%;
    bottom:0%;
    left:0%;
    right:0%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    opacity:0.9;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1scpzfc7/)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.work {
  left: 1%;
  top: 11.5%;
  height: 85.5%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
  border: 1px soid F2F2F2(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: auto;
}
.subject {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 25%;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #0D7BFF;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  position:relative; /* you forgot to add the subject as parent for slider. */
}
.slider {
  top: 70%;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="work">
  <div class="subject" id="1">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="subject" id="2">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="subject" id="3">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="subject" id="4">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="subject" id="5">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="subject" id="6">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You forgot to make subject as position parent for slider. Give `position:relative`to **subject*8

Answer (score 1):

**Snippet**

```css
.work {
left: 1%;
top: 11.5%;
height:85.5%;
width:30%;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
        0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
border: 1px soid F2F2F2(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
z-index:-1;
overflow: auto;
}
.subject {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:25%;
width:90%;
background-color:#0D7BFF;
border-radius:1px;
margin-top:5%;
position: relative;
}

.slider {
top:70%;
bottom:0%;
left:0%;
right:0%;
position:absolute;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
opacity:0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="work">
<div class="subject" id="1">  
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
<div class="subject" id="2">
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

<div class="subject" id="3">
   <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

<div class="subject" id="4">
<div class="slider"></div>
</div>

<div class="subject" id="5">
<div class="slider"></div>
</div>

<div class="subject" id="6">
<div class="slider"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

add this

```
.subject {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  height:25%;
  width:90%;
  background-color:#0D7BFF;
  border-radius:1px;
  margin-top:5%;
  position: relative; // new line
```

}